# Running vbs script from shared network with different credentials.(winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vbscript, smb

I have a requirement witch is to execute a vbscript located in a shared network drive. ie: \SERVER1\shared$\path\script.vbs

To connect to this shared folder I need to pass credentials ie:

DOMAIN\AdminShare
1234

This script has to run with local admin credentials. ie:

.\Administrator
1234

The user witch will execute the exe also has it's own credentials, ie:

DOMAIN\User
1234

How can I manage this scenario?

I've successfully connected to the smb with proper credentials with this class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using BOOL = System.Boolean;
using DWORD = System.UInt32;
using LPWSTR = System.String;
using NET_API_STATUS = System.UInt32;

namespace blah
{
    class UNCAccess
    {
        // FROM: https://ericwijaya.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/access-remote-file-share-with-username-and-password-in-c/
        //
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct USE_INFO_2
        {
            internal LPWSTR ui2_local;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_remote;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_password;
            internal DWORD ui2_status;
            internal DWORD ui2_asg_type;
            internal DWORD ui2_refcount;
            internal DWORD ui2_usecount;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_username;
            internal LPWSTR ui2_domainname;
        }
        [DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern NET_API_STATUS NetUseAdd(
        LPWSTR UncServerName,
        DWORD Level,
        ref USE_INFO_2 Buf,
        out DWORD ParmError);
        [DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern NET_API_STATUS NetUseDel(
        LPWSTR UncServerName,
        LPWSTR UseName,
        DWORD ForceCond);
        private string sUNCPath;
        private string sUser;
        private string sPassword;
        private string sDomain;
        private int iLastError;
        public UNCAccess()
        {
        }
        public UNCAccess(string UNCPath, string User, string Domain, string Password)
        {
            login(UNCPath, User, Domain, Password);
        }
        public int LastError
        {
            get { return iLastError; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Logs in to the shared network with the provided credentials
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UNCPath">unc</param>
        /// <param name="User">user</param>
        /// <param name="Domain">domain</param>
        /// <param name="Password">password</param>
        /// <returns>TRUE OK, ELSE FALSE</returns>
        public bool login(string UNCPath, string User, string Domain, string Password)
        {
            sUNCPath = UNCPath;
            sUser = User;
            sPassword = Password;
            sDomain = Domain;
            return NetUseWithCredentials();
        }
        private bool NetUseWithCredentials()
        {
            uint returncode;
            try
            {
                USE_INFO_2 useinfo = new USE_INFO_2();

                useinfo.ui2_remote = sUNCPath;
                useinfo.ui2_username = sUser;
                useinfo.ui2_domainname = sDomain;
                useinfo.ui2_password = sPassword;
                useinfo.ui2_asg_type = 0;
                useinfo.ui2_usecount = 1;
                uint paramErrorIndex;
                returncode = NetUseAdd(null, 2, ref useinfo, out paramErrorIndex);
                iLastError = (int)returncode;
                return returncode == 0;
            }
            catch
            {
                iLastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                return false;
            }
        }
        ///

        /// Closes the UNC share
        ///  
        /// True if closing was successful
        public bool NetUseDelete()
        {
            uint returncode;
            try
            {
                returncode = NetUseDel(null, sUNCPath, 2);
                iLastError = (int)returncode;
                return (returncode == 0);
            }
            catch
            {
                iLastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I did a process start to run the script as admin:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cscript.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo " + script.FullName
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.StartInfo.UserName = localAdminAccount;
System.Security.SecureString pwd = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char c in localAdminPasswd) { pwd.AppendChar(c); }
p.StartInfo.Password = pwd;
```

The problem is that when the process starts with the new credentials (localAdmin) I'm not able to find the script (the user has changed so no access to the shared network).

I though it was because of the user, so I've also tried to create a launcher to elevate the privileges of the execution of the main application without user interaction (another process.start from the launcher), which works fine, but then the same thing happens (not found).

Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: Wondering why not copy the script to the local machine before executing it with local admin rights? And after execution the local copy of the script can be deleted.

Comment: It is not possible to copy the script, because it relays on other files in that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with two launchers to get the privileges and a runas in the process start, so now i can run the script with the necesary credentials =)